# JavaFX InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have the code:

```
package core;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is my project structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8zzb.jpg

And here is my error message:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.5\lib\idea_rt.jar=54416:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.5\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\nikoe\OneDrive\Arbeit\MysteryShopper\Java\out\production\classes;C:\Users\nikoe\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.xerial\sqlite-jdbc\3.21.0.1\81a0bcda2f100dc91dc402554f60ed2f696cded5\sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.1.jar core.Main
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:473)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:372)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:945)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:973)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:198)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3246)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3210)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3129)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3122)
    at core.Main.start(Main.java:14)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:919)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(PlatformImpl.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:189)
... 1 more
Exception running application core.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

It is weird, because it worked before I added Gradle to the project. After adding Gradle I had to remark "src" as "Sources Root".

This structure is the basic structure that IntelliJ generates for JavaFX projects.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not set a resources folder in your project structure in order the `getResourse` method to work.

Since you don't have the common Java structure, try providing the full path instead:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(new File("fullpath").toURI().toURL());
Parent root = loader.load();
```

And if you want your code to work, you should be having a structure like the following, where `main.fxml` is inside resources directory:

[image]

You can set a folder as "Resources folder" here: **Project Structure->Modules->Sources**

Comment: Restructuring my project worked for me. Additionally I had to put a slash in front of the file like so: Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/main.fxml"));

Comment: @user2037559 This should be the accepted anwser. It's correct, as you acknowledged with your comment.

Comment: never-ever use the file api to lookup resources - it will fail when deploying

Answer (score 0):

As @user2037559 said in comment you can load it like:

```
FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/your-fxml-file.fxml"));
```

or loaded directly

```
Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/your-fxml-file.fxml")), 320, 240);
```

Comment: that's correct only if the resource is located in the default package (where they should not be)

Comment: repeating: this answer is incomplete ..